# Using titlepage.tex in the beamer

Tags: beamer, titles, input

**test_title.tex**

```
{\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}~\\[1cm]

\textsc{\LARGE University of Beer}\\[1.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Final year project}\\[0.5cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Lager brewing techniques \\[0.4cm] }

\HRule \\[1.5cm]

% Author and supervisor
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

}
```

For report I use something like this

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}
\tableofcontents
```

But how to use the same title page in the `beamer`, so that the title page is same?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to use the `\input` inside a frame. For example

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname title.tex}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}~\\[1cm]

\textsc{\LARGE University of Beer}\\[1.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Final year project}\\[0.5cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Lager brewing techniques \\[0.4cm] }

\HRule \\[1.5cm]

% Author and supervisor
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\input{./\jobname title.tex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I put your file inside a `filecontents` environment to use it easily within a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, I put the `demo` option into `beamer`, but you need to remove it on your system to check your logo.